# what is the ECL of a beguiler?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

What is the ECL of the beguiler (Shining south p. 60)? It obviously has an LA +0, but does it start at level 1? (Please site resources to confirm any statements)

Answer (score 6):

The ECL of any creature with no LA is equal to the sum of its racial and character levels.

> [**Level Adjustment and Effective Character Level**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm)
>   To determine the effective character level (ECL) of a monster character, add its level adjustment to its racial Hit Dice and character class levels.

A Beguiler has 1 racial HD. During character creation, it loses its racial HD in favour of the class hit dice [(source)](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monstersAsRaces.htm):

> Creatures with 1 or less HD replace their monster levels with their character levels. The monster loses the attack bonus, saving throw bonuses, skills, and feats granted by its 1 monster HD and gains the attack bonus, save bonuses, skills, feats, and other class abilities of a 1st-level character of the appropriate class.

So the beguiler has no level adjustment when used as a character.

Comment: I assumed those rules applied to creatures with a - for LA, not an LA of 0. (I assume that's a quote from Savage Species).

Comment: Also, the book, Shining South p.60, right before the beguiler, states: "Some creatures presented in this book are suitable for characterters; such monsters have a LA given in their statistics. Creatures without a LA entry are not recommended as characters."

Comment: The beguiler has an entry for Level Adjustment: +0 (cohort). It is not playable as a character (no hands). Regardless of that, a 1HD creature can trade its racial HD for the class hit dice (any creature must have at least 1 HD).

Comment: From the SRD: *Creatures with 1 or less HD replace their monster levels with their character levels. The monster loses the attack bonus, saving throw bonuses, skills, and feats granted by its 1 monster HD and gains the attack bonus, save bonuses, skills, feats, and other class abilities of a 1st-level character of the appropriate class. * - I took the liberty of adding this info to the answer.

Comment: @Mindwin "any creature must have at least 1 HD" doesn't seem true, there are creatures with only half an HD.

Comment: @Mindwin Although it may be recemmended for cohort status, the paragraph directly preceeding the "Level Adjustment: +0 (cohort)" states that "cohort" is a recommendation, not a necessity (as quoted above). Also, at the end of the beguiler description, it gives reference to the Improved Familiar feat for a sorcerer and a page in the DMG p.200.

Comment: @NationWidePants meaning it is **way better** suited to be a PC's companion than a PC itself. A beguiler as a familiar would be awesome for the true sight alone. Also don't overlook that it can do **four** attacks as a full-round (plus rake), and since one of them is a weapon attack it can use [BAB progression](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/22048/11402) to attack even more. One thought: don't allow beguiler rogues into your game, even if you allow beguiler PCs.

Comment: @Mindwin It is hardly a weapon attack. It is probably something like natural attack with stats (damage, crit) of a weapon held in a tail. Or else beguiler's full attack entry would be significantly different.

Comment: @annoyingimp You're 100% correct, it's weilding a short sword, in the example, as stated in the text describing the attack.

Comment: from the book entry - **Full Attack:** 2 claws, bite and shortsword. It indeed wields a weapon, but it seems the claw is the primary attack, and the shortsword is "offhand". Notice it gains multiattack as bonus feat.